# Оптимизация рендеринга 3d wireframe на cpu

Tags: алгоритм, 3d

Итак, имеем геометрию в виде буферов вершин и индексов. Необходимо рендерить эту геометрию в виде wireframe. Очевидно, что простой перебор всех треугольников с отрисовкой каждого ребра приведет к тому, что одни и те же ребра будут рисоваться несколько раз. Есть ли такой способ отбросить повторные отрисовки, который даст ускорение рендеринга?

P.S.: Рендерер полностью программный и выполняется на CPU, поэтому о DirectX/OpenGL не вспоминайте.

Comment: Не знаю, актуально это или нет, но мне кажется, что вы можете реализовать в вашем растеризаторе программный [`Z-culling.`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering#Z-culling)

Comment: Наверно для wireframe'ов это не актуально, потому что рисовать надо все. Вернее у wireframe нету поверхностей и поэтому в сцене нету поверхностей которые перекрываются, которые должен убирать zculling.

Answer (score 2):

Ну что бы не рисовать повторно, нужно помнить все уже нарисованные (в какомнибудь `QuadTree` или `kdTree`).

Можно еще предположить что треугольники с общими линиями находятся рядом в буфере. Тогда для некоторых кусков буфера можно построить нечто вроде `TRIANGLE_STRIP`, выкинув лишние вершины.

Comment: Вопрос в том, даст ли запоминание нарисованных ребер (с построением дерева для каждого кадра и проверкой наличия там очередного ребра) выигрыш в скорости по сравнению с двойным рисованием.

Comment: Это зависит от того насколько медленно работает ваш рендер =). Я бы попробовал, если уж вы пришли к идее, что именно это узкое место программы. Можно сразу в рендер отдавать подготовленные данные, где нет пересекающихся треугольников (Те же стрипы или какие-то свои фигуры, wireframe можно рисовать линиями).

Comment: Рендерер работает достаточно быстро даже без этой оптимизации. Но устранение повторных отрисовок примитивов - это низкоуровневая штука, которая просто должна работать максимально быстро. К тому же, вопрос сам по себе интересен.

Comment: >с построением дерева для каждого кадра
 
Только не надо дерево! Зачем вам логарифмический множитель. Хэш какой-нибудь по номер вершины-номер вершины. Или двумерный массив для небольшого количества последних отрисованных вершин...